# Как через модуль keyboard нажать клавишу Print Screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура, скриншот

Все привет, я начинающий pythоn программист и я пишу своего голосового ассистента. И мне нужно делать скриншот! Я не хочу использовать другие модули(я знаю что через pyautogui это можно реализовать). Кто знает, подскажите как мне это сделать! Буду очень благодарным

Answer (score 0):

имя клавиши printscreen в  модуле keyboard "SNAPSHOT"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. наверно, всё-таки не `SNAPSHOT`, а [`snapshot`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/_canonical_names.py#L33). 2. и, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]